# Free parking for motorbikes in Paris

Tags: budget, automobiles, paris, motorcycles

I was wondering if motorbike parking is free in Paris as it happens to be in, for example, Madrid.

I also read about parking on the pavement on [this page](http://en.parisinfo.com/paris-map/getting-around/traffic-and-parking/):

> "Parking of two-wheeled vehicles on the pavement is tolerated, as long
>   as you are not blocking the way for pedestrians."

Though they recommend not to do it, I don't know how old that information is.

EDIT:

In case you want to park on the street, can motorbikes park on the bays supposed to be for cars? or shall I look for an specific motorbike spot?

Comment: FYI: This question is related to [tag:parking], which is synonym of the [tag:automobiles]

Comment: Oh, great, thanks. I was wondering why I couldn't retag it properly. (I wonder why I cant add `parking` as a tag)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On this website, you can find a car park for your motorcycle, and take a free reservation, but the parking isn't free:

[http://www.parkingsdeparis.com - SELECT A CAR PARK Accepting motorcycles](http://www.parkingsdeparis.com/EN/motorcycle-reservation-map.php)

You can also take a look to this french webpage translated with Google:
[The parking of bikes in Paris and its region](http://translate.google.fr/translate?hl=fr&sl=fr&tl=en&u=http://www.motoservices.com/administration/stationnement-moto-paris.htm)

This is the official weppage about parking policy in Paris:
[What are the objectives of the parking policy?](http://translate.google.fr/translate?hl=fr&sl=fr&tl=en&u=http://www.paris.fr/pratique/stationnement/payer-le-stationnement/paris-les-tarifs-du-stationnement/rub_5779_stand_4812_port_12654)

**[EDIT in response to the edit of the question]**

This webpage can help you to find the response to your inquiry:
[Parking two wheels in Paris: reminder of the rules](http://translate.google.fr/translate?hl=fr&sl=fr&tl=en&u=http://www.asso-scooter.org/Stationnement-deux-roues-a-Paris)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm more interested in street parking as I'm planning to visit many places in the same day. Also as I don't mind to pay the parking for few hours.. in the website you sent I can only see prices for days/weeks

Comment: I edited my answer and added two links that may interest you.

Comment: Hi Pascal, Thanks for you edited answer.. the first link "Parking in the city" is very similar to the one in my question. But your last link clarify a little bit more about the parking on the pavement and how it is completely forbidden in pavements of the Champs Elysees +1 for that.

Comment: I edited my answer and added a link to official information about parking policy in Paris

Comment: Your last edited was perfect. Thank you! I'm planing to move in Paris with the motorbike on Sunday.. so it seems free in any street parking place... I'll update my question with the doubt I have now..

Comment: Ok, so, I update my answer as well ^^

Comment: Great, so in short I must park in a motorbike bay, or take the risk to park in a very wide pavement without disturbing anyone.. :)

Comment: You've got the point ^^